# Can bath and shower be used at same time with diverter?

Tags: shower, bathtub, diverter

When running the bath my son likes both the bath faucet and shower head to be on while he plays. I’m assuming there’s not the same amount of pressure in either as when they are being run solo but is there any issue with this being done?

Comment: if you have the kind of diverter that is a pull up knob in the tub spout, this probably would not be possible. The knob must either be all the way up or down, but you could try. If you have the (older and fancier) type of diverter that is inside the valve body and controlled by a rotating handle, you can divide the flow so some comes out the spout and some comes out the shower. But I don't think this gives much flow out the shower since the path through the spout is so low in resistance to flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both one.  There is no issue.  It will not damage anything.  You are correct in that the pressure on each would be lower than if they were activated by themselves.